# How to use if statement with a span were the text is changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a function when `var roll_time = $('#banner')[0].childNodes[0].textContent;` is `== "Rolling in 25.00..."` i have tried to do so with this code, but i do not get an output. The text in the `<span>` is changing every 10 millisecond.

```js
setInterval(test, 10)

function test(roll_time) {

var roll_time = $('#banner')[0].childNodes[0].textContent;

if (roll_time == "Rolling in 25.20...") {
console.log(success) }
}
```

```html
<span id="banner">Rolling in 25.20...</span>
```

Comment: uhm.... you're calling `test` with no arguments, so `roll_time` is always `undefined` inside of `test`.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `function test(roll_time) {...}` inside there, `roll_time` refers to what is passed as the first argument to `test`. setInterval doesn't call `test` with an argument, therefore that argument is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you are trying to access the roll_time which populate the value during the load.

$('#banner')[0].childNodes[0].textContent is a string, not a reference  and hence if you need to access the string at a later point of time, you need to explicitly read the value from the DOM.

```js
setInterval(test, 10)

function test() {
  var roll_time = $('#banner')[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
  if (roll_time == "Rolling in 25.20...") {
    console.log("success");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="banner">Rolling in 25.20...</span>
```

Comment: The code is correct, but the first sentence is not completely accurate. He was accessing the roll_type argument, which was always undefined.

Comment: Can i use a function instead of console.log?

Comment: You can have any piece of valid code in there. Modified the snippet and its working.